# Ordering a table in PostgreSQL on two columns, so that the value in column X is equal to the value in column Y of the previous record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL, with the following structure:

```
   id        | from     | to 
----------+----------+--------
    11    | 18       |     123
    3     | 88       |     6
    23    | 33       |     18
    7     | 123      |     88
```

I would like to sort that table, so that the value of the "from" field in a given record is equal to the value of the "to" field in the previous record. In other words, the example above, when ordered, should look like this:

```
 id        | from     | to 
----------+----------+--------
    23    | 33       |     18
    11    | 18       |     123
    7     | 123      |     88
    3     | 88       |     6
```

Does someone know how this can be accomplished in PostgreSQL? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using recursive CTEs, keeping track of the root and the level.  The following assumes that you have no cycles:

```
with recursive t (id, fr, t) as (
      values (11, 18, 123), (3, 88, 6), (23, 33, 18), (7, 123, 88)
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.id, t.fr, t.t, t.fr as root, 1 as lev
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.t = t.fr)
      union all
      select t.id, t.fr, t.t, cte.root, cte.lev + 1
      from t join
           cte
           on t.fr = cte.t
     )
select *
from cte
order by cte.root, cte.lev;
```

Note: `from` and `to` are bad column names because they conflict with SQL keywords.

Comment: Hello, indeed I tried it and it works. I do not use "from" and "to" as column names, it was just for the sake of the example. The problem, however, is that indeed there are cycles, like in the example below. Are you aware of a solution that can handle cycles? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @IliyaMarkov . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  You should ask *another* question, with suitable data and a clear definition of how you want to handle cycles.  If you revise this question, you will invalidate this answer, which is rude because it can draw downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will post a new question.